# Showing the intersection of the image and kernel under a linear map of kth power is non-trivial for given k

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, intersection-theory

I am trying to understand how intersections of images and kernals under $k$-th powered linear mappings can be non-trival for some values of $k$ rather than others.

Let $Y$ be a 6 dimensional vector space over some field $\mathbb F$ and $T\in L(Y, Y)$.

Suppose there are two vectors $\mathbf{u}$, $\mathbf{v}$ such that $$T^3(\mathbf{u}) = T^3(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{0} \quad \quad \textrm{  where  } T^2(\mathbf{u}) \textrm{  and  } T^2(\mathbf{v}) \textrm{ are linearly independent. } $$

Let $$N_{1} = \text{span}\{\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\} \quad \textrm{  and  } \quad N_{2} = \text{span}\{T(\mathbf{u}), T(\mathbf{v})\} \quad \textrm{ and } \quad N_{3} = \text{span}\{T^2(\mathbf{u}),T^2(\mathbf{v})\}$$

We know and can prove that $Y = N_{1} ⊕ N_{2} ⊕ N_{3}$.

My question is knowing that $\quad Y=N1⊕N2⊕N3 \quad$ how could we explain why $\quad im(T^2) \cap ker(T^2) \quad$ is not trivial but $\quad im(T^k) \cap ker(T^k) \quad$ is trivial for all $k \geq 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y = N_{1} ⊕ N_{2} ⊕ N_{3}$
tells you a lot of information.

for $k\geq 3$ you have $T^k$ annihilates $N_i$ for arbitrary $i$ so $T^kY =\mathbf 0\implies \ker T^k = Y \text{ and } T^k =\mathbf 0$.  The intersection is zero dimensional.

If $\text{im}T^2 \cap \ker T^2=\{0\}$ then $\text{rank}\big(T^2\big)=\text{rank}\big(T^3\big)=0$ so
$T^2(\mathbf{u}) \textrm{  and  } T^2(\mathbf{v})$  are both zero and hence *not linearly independent*, a contradiction.  Thus $\text{im }T^2 \cap \ker T^2\neq \{0\}$